# iOS Local Notification Scheduling

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Hi i am developing an app that will fetch one qoute from my server everyday and will do a local notification in that app and more when you get inside the app.
I started by implementing Push Notification but then i figured that Local Notifications is what i need.

Official Documentation

> For example, applications that depend on servers for messages or data
>   can poll their   servers for incoming items while running in the
>   background; if a message is ready to view or an   update is ready to
>   download, they can then present a local notification immediately to
>   inform their users.

The work flow of my app is that i need the app to make a post request to get today's quote and fire a local notification for that (that's the hard part) then when user opens the app i think things are easy.
Th issue here is that that request has to be made while my app is not running.
I'm looking for some help on how to acheive that..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple introduced in iOS 7 something called Background fetch.

> The new Background Fetch capability allows your application to ask to fetch data on a regular basis, so when the user launches or re-opens your application, it can start up with the most current data possible.

You can learn how to implement it [here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/)

Another option to consider iOS Silent Push notifications. This will let you update the user database without interacting with him. I'd go with Background fetch, though.

Comment: So you think i must do this: Background fetch -> then the already scheduled localNotification will display the most recent data from UserDefaults ?

Comment: @Hakim If push notification doesn't suit you and fetching a bunch of quotas the first time the user logs in is not an option, the way you described above sounds logical.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can run your app in background unless your app meets one of the background modes specified by apple . If you run your app in background without enabling one of the background modes it may result in app rejection by apple .

Now for your requirement you can simply save the qoute for a particular date from server within local DB once a day whenever user runs the app . By setting local Notification repeat itself at morning everyday you can display qoute of that particular date .